# Signification de « humanité » dans un roman de John Knittel

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, noms

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> si l'on se représente l'extrême misère, tant matérielle que morale, qui régnait dans le pays, on ne peut plus s'étonner que Lauretz eût trouvé beaucoup de gens bien disposés quand il leur parla de sa décision d'extraire l'immense masse d'argent enfouie dans la montagne, masse suffisante pour enrichir chacun et mettre dorénavant l'humanité à l'abri du besoin.

Lorsque l'on parle de l'humanité au sens de groupe, on entend toute l'espèce humaine, et il n'existe pas d'autre définition dans le TLFi ; dans sa phrase, cependant, il évident que ce n'est pas de ce groupe dont  parle Knittel.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/humanit%C3%A9)) B. − **Ensemble des hommes, du genre humain, parfois considéré comme constituant un tout, un être collectif.** Il faut sauver l'humanité et la civilisation à tout prix (Renan, Avenir sc., 1890, p. 326)
> •  Qui dit homme dit humanité. L'homme porte en lui l'humanité. L'homme n'existe pas indépendamment de l'humanité.   Perfectionner l'homme, c'est perfectionner l'humanité. Perfectionner l'humanité, c'est se perfectionner soi-même. P. Leroux, Humanité, t. 1, 1840, p. 269.

Comment comprendre cette construction ? Faut-il entendre par là, selon un quelconque processus elliptique quelque chose comme « la portion d'humanité du lieu » ? Serait-il question d'un autre sens de « humanité » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knittel n'utilise pas ici un autre sens de « humanité ». Le livre a été initialement écrit en anglais, et *Google Books Snippet View* montre que l'orignal était:

> at that Lauretz found many ready listeners when he spoke of his determination to dig out the vast wealth of silver that lay buried in the mountains, wealth vast enough to make everybody rich, to save mankind from all future want.

Comment: Never has been heard of such an amount of wealth buried in any such small portion of the globe, but I guess your interpretation has to be the proper one.

Comment: The book says Lauretz told his listeners that this vast amount of wealth was buried there. It doesn't actually, at least not in this excerpt, say that he was telling the truth. (And from the wording, I'd guess he wasn't.) Presumably, this is clarified in the rest of the book.